# Google maps API - improving slow performance with many datapoints

Tags: performance, google-maps-api-3, response

sI am sending >25,000 data points to the API and clustering them. Perhaps not surprisingly, the loading time is becoming very slow. Code fragments are here:

```
        var l = huge_array_of_data.length;
        for ( i = 0; i < l; i++) {

             var strain_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i]['lat'], data[i]['lng']);

             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: strain_latlng,
                       title: data[i][field2show]
             });
             markers.push(marker);

}
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, opt);
```

I assume the 1,000s of calls to google.maps.LatLng is causing the delay. I would like to do this with many more markers - many 100s of thousands - and that is obviously not going to work. Is there a way to reduce the traffic and push the work to Google's side ?  I can't amalgamate points before sending them because I am using the clusterer to generate heat maps and similar based on the number of points at a place, even when they have the same lat and lng.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Use tile based rendering.  Google uses tile based rendering for `FusionTablesLayer` and `KmlLayer` (but neither cluster markers).  If you want clustering you will have to spin your own.

Comment: I see no reason why this question got marked down. The use-case is unusual, and the initial solution is clearly sub-optimal, but that doesn't make the question unworthy of consideration. Thank you for asking @Steve. I have a similar problem and have to throttle the number of data points to something that won't bring the browser to its knees.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the markers is to only send markers from the server which lie inside the bounds of your map's current view.

As for the heat map you don't need to have multiple markers for the same location to make it work. There is a weight field for each point in a heat map. You can change that based on the number of points at the same location. So normally the weight would be 1. But if there are 10 markers at that same location you can set it to 10. This will have the same effect on the heat map as having 10 markers.